# Export rotable 3D plots from Python to HTML

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I need to export a rotable 3D plot to HTML, just like [WriteWebGL does in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgl/versions/0.100.54/topics/writeWebGL), but from Python / matplotlib.

When ran in a Jupyter notebook, you can generate a in interactive plot like this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
ax.scatter3D(xdata, ydata, zdata, c=zdata, cmap='Greens');
```

(source code for this sample [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/04.12-Three-Dimensional-Plotting.ipynb#scrollTo=1c0OOBjyaX3t))

As noted, 3D plots can be rotated by the user. How can I get this interactivity exported to HTML from Python?

Answer (score 5):

Does it have to be matplotlib? You could use plotly for that.

Here is a simple example. This modifies an existing empty file called test.html which you then can open in web browser to use the interactive 3D-plot.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# Helix equation
t = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
x, y, z = np.cos(t), np.sin(t), t

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=12,
        color=z,                # set color to an array/list of desired values
        colorscale='Viridis',   # choose a colorscale
        opacity=0.8
    )
)])

# tight layout
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0))
fig.write_html("test.html") #Modifiy the html file
fig.show()
```

Comment: Nice solution. I would still look for one that only depends on matplotlib, for lesser dependencies.